# How to find out what fields are referring to a NetSuite custom field

Tags: netsuite

I have a problem deleting a custom field from a vendor in NetSuite. When I try to delete it I get the following error message.

> This custom field cannot be deleted because it is referred to by other custom fields

I've looked at many of my other custom fields and columns but I can't find any that are referencing this one. Is there a way to find all fields that refer to a particular custom field?

Comment: What type of field is that? (free-form text, list/record, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you might be using this `custom field` value some where else. I'm not sure if there is any inbuilt functionality to identify the other fields which are being referred by your `custom field`. I had a similar issue but I solved it using mass update. I set that field value for all the vendor as blank then I was able to delete the custom field.

In case it is a custom list field then follow the steps bellow :
First delete the list from `Setup > Customization > Transaction Item` Options, then from the `Custom Item Fields` and then finally from the `Custom Lists`

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down the list of fields to check, go to Customization->Lists, Records & Fields->Entity Fields. Sort that list by the Vendor column. That is the list that needs to be checked. Open each of these fields, and check that the 'Field' under the 'Validation and Defaulting' tab is not your custom field that you want to delete. Then check the values on the 'Sourcing and Filtering' tab as well.

Good luck, and hopefully there is not too many vendor fields to check this way!