# Netsuite + how can I delete a deployed script?

Tags: netsuite

When I try to delete a script from the file cabinet I get this message:

> This record cannot be deleted, because it is referred to by other records.

Any idea how to find those records so I can delete them?

Comment: Maybe you'll find something useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011907/how-to-find-out-what-fields-are-referring-to-a-netsuite-custom-field

Answer (score 3):

As the message indicates, you cannot delete any record on which other records depend.  In the case of a script *file* in the file cabinet, it could be referenced by script *records* (under Customization > Scripting > Scripts), which in turn may be referenced by script *deployments* (Customization > Scripting > Script Deployments).

In order to delete the file, you must trace this dependency chain backwards.  So, first delete any deployments of the script, then delete the script record, then the file.